# Убрать пустоты рядом с изображениями

Tags: css

```css
img {vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="15" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77"><img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="15" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77"><img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="15" height="60">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
<img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77">
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как избавится от этих пустот выделенных красным цветом?

Comment: Вы только заголовок прочитали? Вопрос сам прочитать не думали?

Comment: Если бы Вы в заголовке написали не "Убрать...", а "Как убрать...", то не было бы ненужных комментариев и "минуса в репе" наверно не случилось бы, но это естественно ИМХО.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну наверно так...
В мелких flex выставлено выравнивание сверху вниз (column), а общий блок mama берет внутренние блоки flex, и в свою очередь выдает им display: flex - гоирзонатльное выравнивание.

```css
.flex {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
.mama {display: flex;}

img {margin: 4px;}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="50" height="60">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="57" height="80">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="44" height="54">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="78" height="57">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="32" height="75">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="22" height="77">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="75" height="22">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77">
    <img src="https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg" width="55" height="77">
  </div>
</div>
```